# Augeas resource not applying changes to config. file

Tags: puppet, augeas

I'm testing some config changes with Augeas, and I can see Puppet picking up the changes but they're not actually applied to disk:

```
Notice: Augeas[db-connection](provider=augeas):
--- /opt/myconfigfile.xml       2017-09-11 11:56:18.072779400 +0000
+++ /opt/myconfgfile.xml.augnew        2017-09-11 14:54:57.403377000 +0000

Notice: /Stage[main]/myserver::Configuration_someconfig/Augeas[db-connection]/returns: executed successfully
```

But I also see this:

```
   Info: Stage[main]: Unscheduling all events on Stage[main]
```

Comment: You'll need to actually supply your code and more information to help us understand what might be wrong.

Comment: i have fixed this now, i'm not sure what the issue was but i would say there was probably a typo involved in the path at least.

Answer (score 1):

```
   augeas { 'test1':
        lens    => 'Xml.lns',   
        tag     => 'my-config',
        incl => $mysystem_xml,
        context => "/files$mysystem_xml/properties",
        changes => [ 
        "set entry[#attribute/key='ProviderType']/#text $myserver::provider_type", 
        ],
      }
```